# What is this brown sticky stuff on my soffits?

Tags: roof, cleaning

I recently had my roof replaced and some brown patches started appearing under some of the new plywood. It appears to be dry to the touch, although there are some beads of similarly colored goo on the fascia board nearby that I was able to wipe away. Does anyone know what it could be coming from?

[image]

Comment: Tannin and pine tar

Comment: Or if they used tar paper under the shingles, the tar is running along the roofing nails from the heat of the roof. And technically, that is your "eave", not a soffit. A soffit would be an additional ceiling under the eave, usually to HIDE what you are seeing. but in your case because of the vents, a soffit would not be a good idea.